# How to draw colored routes on the google map using c#?

Tags: c#, google-maps, routes

I'm making c# application. I use google map and I want to draw two routes with different color. For example: The first one I want to be red and second one-green but both of them are green.
I want to change second color so that the first one ***`stay the same`***.

this is my code:

```
        PointLatLng start1 = new PointLatLng(42.252938, 42.680411);
        PointLatLng end1 = new PointLatLng(42.256321, 42.675658);
        GDirections dir1;
        var path1 = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out dir1, start1, end1, false, false, true, true, true);
        GMapRoute route1 = new GMapRoute(dir1.Route, "path1");
        route1.Stroke.Color = Color.Red;
        GMapOverlay lay1 = new GMapOverlay("route1");
        lay1.Routes.Add(route1);
        map.Overlays.Add(lay1);


        PointLatLng start2 = new PointLatLng(42.259188, 42.670733);
        PointLatLng end2 = new PointLatLng(42.259617, 42.673362);
        GDirections dir2;
        var path2 = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out dir2, start2, end2, false, false, true, true, true);
        GMapRoute route2 = new GMapRoute(dir2.Route, "path2");
        route2.Stroke.Color = Color.Green;
        GMapOverlay lay2 = new GMapOverlay("route2");
        lay2.Routes.Add(route2);
        map.Overlays.Add(lay2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the 'route.Stroke.Color' to a color, Set the 'route.Stroke' to a new Pen(Color.Red) (for example).

```
route1.Stroke = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red);
```

This should then work.

Note** (I think it has to be a 'new' object because the graphics object which draws it takes a reference to the Static Color object that you pointed it to and then you changed this reference when you changed the route.Stroke.Color again such that they both drew Green?!)